# Type of props is not recognized

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have 2 different components for the title prop, `Title` and `MainTitle`:

```
import Title from "./Title";
import MainTitle from "./MainTitle"

interface HeaderProps {
  title: ReactElement<typeof Title>;
}
```

The code above works when I use `Title` as the title prop of Header.
But it also works when I use `MainTitle` instead, without defining `typeof MainTitle`.

How can I define that ONLY Title would be accepted inside of that interface?

Comment: [How do I prevent two types from being structurally compatible?](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#how-do-i-prevent-two-types-from-being-structurally-compatible)

Comment: @VLAZ Can you please show a tiny example? I'm not sure I understand what they mean on that page according to my example